# Sending cookies with Cordova Websockets on Android

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, cookies, websocket

With the last Android-Webview update (52.0.2743.98), I am having really hard times sending cookies to my websocket server using Cordova.

I am using cookies for authentication and this code used to work perfectly well before the update:
 `this.websocket = new WebSocket(url);`

I even tried another way to force cookie headers during handshake, but it does not work:

```
this.websocket = new WebSocket(
  url,
  [],
  { headers: { Cookie: 'key=value' } }
);
```

Here is the server response:

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://api.my.url/dev/ws' failed:
Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 403
```

and under the Network Tab in Chrome:

```
Request:
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en-GB,en-US;q=0.8
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:Upgrade
Host:api.host.com
Origin:file://
Pragma:no-cache
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions:permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits
Sec-WebSocket-Key:<random value>==
Sec-WebSocket-Version:13
Upgrade:websocket
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; Nexus 6P Build/MTC19X; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/52.0.2743.98 Mobile Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:com.domain

Response:
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:file://
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8
Date:Thu, 11 Aug 2016 13:47:09 GMT
Server:nginx/1.8.1
Set-Cookie:key=<random id>; Path=/
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
Vary:Accept-Encoding
```

Note that it still works on Chrome and on IOS (and previous versions of Android-Webview)

any recommendation ?

Comment: Dont think we can explicitly pass headers on websocket by protocol.                                             However default cookies should have got passed with each request normall http or ws . I have also faced same issue on updated version of android.

Comment: Did you found a solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the better option to resolve your problem is change the browser. Now you use a chrome browser for display a hybrid app, you can change this default browser.

I'd the same problem with the WebSockets and I used the CrossWalk browser and I didn't have any problems with WebSockets. You can check the CrossWalk project in this page: https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/android.html

I'm using Ionic to implement my app and only I had to run this command to install CrossWalk Browser:

ionic browser add crosswalk

Comment: Crosswalk now is not maintained anymore, for KitKat and upper they suggest to use Android System WebView which now is a single updateable "app"